# Javascript for creating excel like cursor movement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the below form to get user input and update to a mysql table. As there will be about 25 rows in the table given below and each row has about 7 input boxes. I need a simple javascript function to move around the input boxes using arrow keys horixontally and vertically. At present only tab can be used and the tab moves serially from left to right and is cumbersome. I found some editable grids but that are complex and I know how to handle data and need only moviing around. Thanks in advance

NoEleLocationDose Rate (mGy/h)    Tritium 
    (DAC)  Part (DAC) Iodine (DAC)   Surface Cont. (Bq/cm2)

```
   <?php 
        $db=mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die("could not connect");
        $secsql= "SELECT * FROM location ORDER BY loc_id";
        $result_sec=@mysql_query($secsql) or die(mysql_error());
  $rc=0;
            while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result_sec))
                { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".++$rc."</td>";
                echo "<td><input size='5' id='".$row2['elevation']."' value='".$row2['elevation']."' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input id='".$row2['loc_id']."' value='".$row2['location']."' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input size='5' id='dose' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input size='5' id='h3' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input size='5' id='part' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input  size='5'id='iod' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input  size='5'id='cont' /></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }



?>

   </table>



   <div align="center">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" width="30" />
   </div>

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right start, by giving each editable `input` field a unique ID.  However, you also have an error, in that as the `while` loop processes multiple rows, the last 5 ids (e.g., `id='dose'`) will be duplicated, and they need to be different.  I suggest you change ALL the `id=` to `name=` and give them similar-but-but-still-unique IDs, such as `id='AA'` and `id='AB'` and `id='BA'` and so on.  Then, in your javascript, you can fetch the whole two-dimensional array of input objects using something like this:

```
var cels, x, y;  //globals
cels=[];
for(x=0; x<7; x++)
{ tmp="ABCEDFG".substr(x,1);
  cels[x]=[];
  for(y=0; y<25; y++)
    cels[x][y]=document.getElementById(tmp+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY".substr(y,1));
}
```

That code needs to be executed when the page is loaded from the web server, along with whatever-other page-initialization stuff you already do.  Getting back to your PHP, you also need to give each of those `input` fields an `onkeydown` function call (the same call!), say,

```
echo "<td><input size='5' name='dose' id='AC' onkeydown='tstkey(event, id);' /></td>";
```

That function would look something like this:

```
function tstkey(e, i)
{ x="ABCDEFG".indexOf(i.substr(0,1));
  y="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXY".indexOf(i.substr(1,1));
  if(e.keyCode == 13)     //Enter key pressed?
  { x++;        //index of next cell in current row
    if(x>6)     //off the end?
    { x=0;      //first cell
      y++;      //next row
      if(y>24)  //off the end?
        y=0;    //first row
  } }
//    if(e.keyCode == down-arrow, up-arrow, etc )
//      do appropriate manipulation of x and y coordinates   

  cels[x][y].focus();  //move cursor to other cell in 2D array of input fields
  return;
}
```

Note that with this code you would need a SUBMIT button to send the data to the Web Server.  Also, since this more of a suggestion than a complete detailed Answer, I haven't tested the code for typos and such.  Some experimentation with the browser's built-in javascript debugger will reveal the keycodes for uparrow, downarrow, etc.